# Bad Request from mongolab

Tags: mlab

Below is my controller:

```
'use strict';
app.controller('editTaskCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams',  function($scope, $http, $routeParams){
var taskid = $routeParams.id;


   $http.get('https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/dothis/collections/newtask?q={"_id":'+taskid+'}&apiKey=_______-yyNsxk___-____21jxrS___').success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

      $scope.lists = data;
       console.log(data);
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) { alert(status); });  

}]);
```

When i send a request to mongolab it gives me "Bad Request".

here is my requst URL:

```
GET https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/dothis/collections/newtask?q={%22_id%22:56b06ff8e4b0f641cb6d3a76}&apiKey=_______-yyNsxk___-____21jxrS___ 400 (Bad Request)
```

Here I want a mongodb collection document using mongolab api and collection id i.e. (_id);

please tell me where is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Querying on the _id field via the MongoLab Data API takes a different format than other queries.

```
GET /databases/{database}/collections/{collection}/{_id}

Example:
https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/my-db/collections/my-coll/4e7315a65e4ce91f885b7dde?apiKey=myAPIKey
```

Please refer to our documentation for further information: http://docs.mongolab.com/data-api/.